# EmberJS app and Broccoli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, webpack, ember-cli, broccolijs

I have an Ember app. My question is regarding the usage of Broccoli.

Now it is said that Broccoli is the default build tool for Ember-CLI

But I do not find Brocfile.js anywhere within my project.

Just wanted to understand how is Broccoli really used within an Ember project. Also in what practical scenarios do we have to change/define any configurations related to that

Answer (score 2):

`ember-cli` is basically wrapping `broccoli`. Your [`ember-cli-build.js` is basically a modified version of the `brocfile`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#brocfile-transition). You can easily extend it with tools like `broccoli-merge-trees` or `broccoli-funnel`.

To modify the broccoli pipeline you usually hook into it after `ember-cli`. `app.toTree()` returns a normal broccoli tree, you're free to extend this with `broccoli-merge-trees`:

```
return new MergeTrees([app.toTree(), myCustomTree]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was actually looking for. Just one last question - Does it make any difference to the configs if the project is an Ember app V/s an Ember addon.

Comment: The addons [`ember-cli-build.js` has no effect](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addon-ember-cli-build)